# Modelling sequence order in OWL-DL ontology

Tags: sequence, ontology, owl

As by default sequence order is not maintained in an OWL ontology. How can i model sequence in an OWL-DL ontology ?

Comment: Was there nothing in the papers found by searching "owl dl sequence order" that you could use? e.g. http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-216/submission_12.pdf

Comment: I have two confusion when two use rdf-list and owl-list and do jena have support for rdf-list and owl-list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to model a sequence and order its elements is to just introduc a `hasNext` property to capture sequence order:

```
Class: SequenceItem
    EquivalentTo: 
        hasNext only SequenceItem

ObjectProperty: hasNext 
    Domain: 
       SequenceItem
    Range: 
       SequenceItem
    InverseOf:
       hasPrevious
```

Then, assuming the items you want to sequence in order are represented as instances, you can capture their order in the sequence like so:

```
SequenceItem: item_1
    hasNext: 
         item_2
```

Answer (score 0):

OWL allows you to state e.g.:

- every item follows at most one item.
- every item is followed by at most one item.
- every first-item is an item that follows no item.
- Item1 is an item and is followed by Item2.
- ...

These statements allow you to describe sequences (possibly open-ended, i.e. with an infinite model).

(The above statements were written in ACE, use the [ACE parser](https://github.com/Attempto/APE) to convert them to OWL, where `item` becomes a class, `follows` becomes an object property and `Item1` and `Item2` are individuals.)

Comment: Can you provide an example of these statements?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want. The statements do form an example of an OWL ontology (expressed in ACE) whose models are certain sequences.