# Assigning sequence in OWL using Protege

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, linked-data

I have this axiom in my ontology

```
:drug :givenAs (({dose1}) or ({dose2}) or ({dose3}))
 and (not ({dose4}))
```

The syntax isn't correct as per Turtle, but I hope you get the point.

I'd like to assert that dose1 is followed by dose2 followed by dose3.

I checked out [Modelling sequence order in OWL-DL ontology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789763/modelling-sequence-order-in-owl-dl-ontology) but it doesn't exactly solve my case. That is because I'm dealing with individuals only, not classes in this case.

What is an elegant way to assert the sequence?

The axiom is for identifying errors in data records. For instance, I'd like the ontology to point out an error if there's `:drug :givenAs :dose2 .` without `:drug :givenAs :dose1 .`

UPDATE 1

I tried the `hasNext` property as suggested. I can link the individuals using the property. However, I'm not sure this applies to my context:

```
Class: SequenceItem
    EquivalentTo: 
        hasNext only SequenceItem
```

I do not have a class and want to avoid it if appropriate. How do I still assign sequence?

UPDATE 2

I added the class axiom as mentioned. The reasoners find no error. However, they also do not identify erroneous records where dose2 precedes dose1. I asserted that the class `Dose` is equivalent to:

```
Dose
and hasNext only Dose
```

The issue, I think, is I don't assert anywhere that no dose2 is possible before dose1 and no dose3 is possible before dose2 and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

The addition of a `hasNext` property ala [Modelling sequence order in OWL-DL ontology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789763/modelling-sequence-order-in-owl-dl-ontology) would work just as well.  Just assert the `hasNext` on the individuals (see last para).

Another way to specify ordering is through an RDF list, i.e. `(:dose1 ;dose2 :dose3)`.  The list is an ordered enumerated list and you can use rdf:first/rdf:rest to query elements in order.

The last idea is to specify an ordering property.  Similar to the `hasList` solution, a `sequenceNum` property could be added an attached to the dose objects, e.g.:

```
:dose1 :sequenceNum 1 .
:dose1 :sequenceNum 2 .
:dose1 :sequenceNum 3 .
```

Then use the numbering to specify which occurs before the other.