# Sequence in OWL using protege

Tags: sequence, owl, ontology, semantic-web, linked-data

I'm trying to define a sequence of action in OWL using protege. I have read the following topics:

- [Modelling sequence order in OWL-DL ontology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789763/modelling-sequence-order-in-owl-dl-ontology)
- [Assigning sequence in OWL using Protege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421022/assigning-sequence-in-owl-using-protege?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The problem I have is that an individual can be in different course of action. I hope the following example helps:

I have the class "Action" and class "Course of Action".

For Action I have the following individuals: "Say Hello", "Give Your Name", "Ask a question", "Say Good Bye"

For Course of Action I want to have 2 different sequences:

1. Say Hello - Give your Name - Say Good Bye
2. Say Hello - Ask a question - Say Good Bye

"Say Hello" will be linked to two individual by the property hasNext and I will not be able to find the exact course of action.  Is it possible to do what I want in OWL?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you can model, but you'll need to distinguish between the actual sequences and the steps within them.  This is typically modeled by a linked list.  RDFS defines a list vocabulary with `rdf:first`, `rdf:rest` and `rdf:nil`, but you probably don't want to co-opt that terminology in your OWL ontology.  Instead, you'd do something like this

```
:seq1step1 :hasAction :SayHello ;
           :hasNextStep :seq1step2 .

:seq1step2 :hasAction :GiveYourName ;
           :hasNextStep :seq1step3 .

:seq1step3 :hasAction :SayGoodbye ;
           :hasNextStep :emptySeq .


:seq2step1 :hasAction :SayHello ;
           :hasNextStep :seq2step2 .

:seq2step2 :hasAction :AskAQuestion ;
           :hasNextStep :seq2step3 .

:seq2step3 :hasAction :SayGoodbye ;
           :hasNextStep :emptySeq .
```

This does mean your queries need to be in terms of *steps* rather than the specific *actions*, but that's actually necessary because otherwise:

> "Say Hello" will be linked to two individual by the property hasNext and I will not be able to find the exact course of action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's finally what I did. It's not exactly what I wanted, but I think it is the best solution I found. Thank you !